# S3Blob.java for play 2

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-s3, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am looking to see if anyone has found or implemented a Play 2 version of James Ward's S3Blob.java class (https://github.com/jamesward/S3-Blobs-module-for-Play).

**History**

We've been very happily using James Wards S3Blob.java class in our Play 1.2 app for years now, but we've recently decided to upgrade to Play 2 (2.4.3 to be precise). The S3Blob class defines a play.db.Model.BinaryField implementation which provides a self-contained means of adding an Amazon S3 file column to a MySQL table.

I spent many hours trying to upgrade S3Blob.java to Play 2 yesterday with limited success. I'm wondering if anyone has done this work already. The main problem I am encountering is that Play 2 no longer provides a Model interface (and hence no Model.BinaryField). The recommended replacement Model interface (com.avaje.ebean.Model) does not contain a BinaryField interface or anything similar.

I spent a good amount of time composing an S3BlobScalarTypeConverter implementation of the ebean.config.ScalarTypeConverter interface, which seemed like it might be the way to do this, but I never could get it to work and the documentation for that interface is woeful, with nary a complete example to be found. My S3BlobScalarTypeConverter class was actually called during startup by an ebean initialiseScalarConverters() method, which certainly seemed promising, but the wrapValue() and unwrapValue() routines within the class were never called, and my app continued to persist a null value to the S3Blob db field.

I finally sort of hacked over the problem by calling the wrapValue() and unwrapValue() methods myself in the S3Blob persist and read routines. This appears to be working correctly for the time being, but I would be most interested to see if anyone has solved this problem using a supported play or ebean interface.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, are you still trying to do this?  If you are then ping me or post on the Ebean google group etc.  There are a number of things here ... ScalarTypeConverter is very unlikely to be the correct approach and in addition Ebean supports streaming large blobs and I'm interested in built in caching for File and S3Blob would be similar.

Comment: Just as a side note. With these types of issues/questions I'd recommend asking or cross posting to the Ebean google group where you will get the attention of the Ebean developers (like me).